# Remove UITableView separator line

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to remove the line between 2 views. The line that separates 2 `UITableViewCell`s:

[image]

I declared table view as following:

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 85.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

So i actually wrote -         `self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;`

Why does it still exist?

Comment: Try this: `cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, cell.bounds.size.width, 0.f, 0.f);` in `cellForRow` method

Comment: You can also use this line on `viewWillLayoutSubView` method of you `viewController self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;`

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Objective-C :

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

Swift:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
```

Swift 5.0 renamed it in :

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none
```

Apply the line in viewDidLoad() method.

If you want to do it from nib file, set the tableView's Separator property to `None`

Comment: thank you,  that was a problem in storyboard, i already set that in .m file.

Comment: Setting `separatorStyle` seems to have no effect unless the table view is in the window's view hierarchy. If you have a table view on some `UIView` subclass, you can set it in `didMoveToWindow` method.

Comment: Can be simplified to `self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none` as mentioned by @NiravPanchal.

Answer (score 18):

For **Swift 4:**

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

Answer (score 17):

For **Swift 5** :

```
 viewDidLoad(){
     tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCell.SeparatorStyle.none
    }
```

For **Objective-C** :

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

---

### or you can use interface builder instead

[image]

---

### For more information

[SeparatorStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614909-separatorstyle)

Comment: thanks for suggesting interface builder. I did not know that

Answer (score 8):

**Hide tableView separators using UI**

Here you select TableView 'Separator' property as 'None'.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KyH5.png

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following code because it will not remove the line separators of the sections.:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // Your code here //

    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 0.f, 0.f);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

My problem was when I add tableView trough code and I have separate func to show tableview and add it on mainView (slide from bottom) I needed to add this
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
in that func where tableView is added on mainView and constraint it.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4.2 you can conveniently use dot notation on a `tableView`'s `separatorStyle`. Like so:

`tableView.separatorStyle = .none`

Answer (score 3):

As @gonsee point out:
*"Setting separatorStyle seems to have no effect unless the table view is in the window's view hierarchy. If you have a table view on some UIView subclass"*

You should set the seperatorStyle in viewDidAppear if you your table in UIView.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.contentView.documentTableView.separatorStyle = .none
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In **viewDidLoad** add **tableView.separatorStyle = .none**

Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none // <---
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can archive these things in different ways

1. you can also use this one line of code in `viewDidLoad()`

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
   }
   ```

---

2. You can do it on a storyboard

   [image: select none]

---

3. set the code in `viewDidLoad()`

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      tableView.separatorStyle = .none
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

add this line

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```